# Array returns always null

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have this part of code here (i have of course a contructor etc. and created objects)

```
function searchUsers($term)
{
    $searchUserSQL = "SELECT userID, givenName, familyName from userbase where givenName or familyName = :name";
    $searchUserPrepare = $this->prepare($searchUserSQL);
    $searchUserPrepare->bindParam(':name', $term);
    $searchUserPrepare->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $searchUserPrepare->execute();
    $searchUserResult = $searchUserPrepare->fetchAll();
    foreach($searchUserResult as $row){
            $row['userBaseData']=$this['givenName'];
            $results[] = $row;
        }
        return $results;
}
```

But results is always NULL. When I test this qry in PHPmyAdmin I also get no result.

But in my table userbase there is a column name named userID, givenName and familyName, and the search term is also correct. I don't know what I'm doing wrong with my qry. Any help?

Comment: declare your $results array before your foreach loop. $results = new array();

Comment: Can you var_dump() and post the results?

Comment: add something like this to execute: if (!$searchUserPrepare->execute()) 
        echo "execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;

Comment: actually this may be your problem $row['userBaseData']=$this['givenName']; if $row is is the row from the table, what is $this?

Comment: Quick question: Should `$row['userBaseData']=$this['givenName'];` be `$this['givenName'] = $row['userBaseData'];`? Are you setting an additional array element or redefining the row results?

Comment: @Asok i think you're right, i think he's trying to set $row with nothing, and that's why it's returning nothing

Comment: most of the errors here are easily detectable using a debugger, you may want to spend some time to learn on how to set it up and use it.

Comment: For a debugger you can learn about using XDebugger for php using Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT userID, givenName, familyName from userbase where givenName or familyName = :name`

I'm not even sure how that query would ever work, specifically in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT
    u.userID
  , u.givenName
  , u.familyName
FROM `userbase` u
WHERE u.givenName = :given_name
  OR u.familyName = :family_name;
```

Then bind `$term` to both `:given_name` and `:family_name`

---

**EDIT** The whole thing together *(rewritten)*

```
function searchUsers( $term )
{
    $sql = <<<SQL
SELECT
    u.userID
  , u.givenName
  , u.givenName AS `userBaseData`
  , u.familyName
FROM `userbase` u
WHERE u.givenName = :given_name
  OR u.familyName = :family_name;
SQL;

    $stmt = $this->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->bindParam( ":given_name", $term, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $stmt->bindParam( ":family_name", $term, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $stmt->execute();

    return ( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 )
        ? $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )
        : array();

}
```

**EDIT 2**

Really not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the `$row['userBaseData'] = $this['givenName']`

Comment: Might depend on the DBMS/SQL dialect – but I think `where givenName` would just evaluate the contents of that column as a boolean value, according to the rules of the system.

Comment: If we don't find anything it's an empty array, just with the rowCount() you will know, but that's not the problem of a null array... found or not found cannot be null the query response.

Comment: @CBroe perhaps, I assumed MySQL since it is PHP and PDO and tested it on a local mysql server. `where givenName or familyName = 'something'` returned no results.

Comment: @rokimoki This is true, I could just replace it with `return $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );` I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $results = array();    
    foreach($searchUserResult as $row){
        $row['userBaseData'] = ??????;
        $results[] = $row;
    }
    return $results;
```

Replace the ?????? with correct variable. Current var name is wrong!

Now at least you will return empty array ..

Comment: he should change $row too, something like this foreach($searchUserResult as $this){
        $row['userBaseData'] = $this['givenName'];

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using PDO, then you have to connect to the database first:

```
$conector = new connection("server","database"); // Your custom class to connect to a DB
$con = $conector->connect(); // Return the connector
$con->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8'); // A must have
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // A must have to handle exceptions and know better the errors that it gives, use try - catch
$consulta = $con->prepare("SELECT userID, givenName, familyName from userbase where givenName or familyName = :name;");
$consulta->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$data = array('name' => $term);
$consulta->execute($data);
foreach($consulta as $row){
        $row['userBaseData']=$this['givenName'];
        $results[] = $row;
}
return $results;
```

Try that code.